# ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged event: why the SelectedText propery is not changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, combobox

I would like to get the text of the selected item in combobox whenever the selection is changed.

I therefore use the `SelectedIndexChanged event`, but the combobox text does not changed. it remains empty.

```
private void myCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string myTxt = myCombobox.SelectedText; //myTxt is null.
        }
```

Just when I select twice the same item, the text is changed accordingly.

Should I use another event?
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you've understood what `SelectedText` is. It sounds like you want `Text`.

Comment: Use combobox SelectedItem instead of SelectedText

Comment: @Eins, but I need the text.

Comment: If the type of your combobox data source is a list of strings just convert selected item value to string, if not, convert to type that you use and select the property that contains your text.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the text that is in the combobox after it is selected then you would want to do something like this:

```
private void myCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myTxt = myCombobox.Text;
    }
```

This will take all the text from the combobox, don't forget to look at your Delegate in the Designer to ensure this actually occurs once the Combobox is changed

Comment: Thanks. This seems not to help. The problem is that the index is changed and the event is fired before the text is changes too. Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you trying to apply the text from the combobox? If you are doing a button click event or something similar you can just use myCombobox.Text anywhere you need it and whatever is in the combobox at the time of the event will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Text of a selected index you have to use the .Text property, not SelectedText.

For after the value is selected use the SelectionChangeCommited Event.

Try this:

```
private void myCombobox_SelectionChangeCommited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string myTxt = myCombobox.Text;
}
```

You can also test SelectedItem as well, not sure if that will solve a null value.

```
string myTxt = myCombobox.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()
```

But I think the latter would be used more for conversion issues. Try both, let me know how it works out.

Comment: @iDillion, Thanks. This seems not to help. The problem is that the index is changed and the event is fired before the text is changes too. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3165438 Ah, sorry I misunderstood your question, have you experimented with the _SelectionChangeCommit_ event instead of the SelectedIndexChanged? SelectionChangeCommit will fire after the value is selected.

Comment: @iDillion, Nice idea. I tried: when I change the selection, the text still the old selection. Only if I select the new selection twice I get the new text. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3165438 well that's odd, have you use _myCombobox.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()_ in both events and seen if that works? That should get the current item.

Comment: @iDillion, TNX, but there is no Text property to the SelectedItem.

Comment: @user3165438 _myCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString()_?

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed need the ComboBox.SelectedText (I also suggest you carefully read the description for this property before deciding https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedtext(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void myCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var originalValue = myCombobox.SelectedText;

    var tempCb = sender as ComboBox;
    if(tempCB != null)
    {
        var newValue = tempCb.SelectedText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for getting Null value is because you are using the 'SelectedText' property. In order to Get the current value You have to use the Text property

```
private void myCombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string cmbTextValue = this.myCombobox.text;
}
```

Hopes this will solve the problem :)

Comment: Thanks. The problem now is : I have to select the new selection twice in order to get the new text. Any ideas?

Comment: Will u please explain what is the purpose of ur program and list which all event are u handling there(combobox)